# Blender or 3Ds Max

Tags: 3d, graphics, animation, models

I am starting a 3D video game project and I do not know whether I should use Blender or 3Ds max. Other sites say to use Blender because it has similar functionality and it is free, but I need to know which one I should use completely disregarding the cost. I have some experience with 3D modeling and I have used both programs before. For the game I will be making landscapes, buildings and small models (ex. weapons).

I would like to hear your opinions on which program would be better for me to use disregarding the price.

Comment: "Which technology" questions are off-topic here, especially ones as broad as this.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, it all depends on what you feel comfortable with. Blender can be pretty confusing for some and it takes a while to learn as it is a bit different from standard modelling programs. If you plan to have others help, determine what they prefer and base your decision with that.

The main selling point to blender is that most indie developers don't want to spend a lot of money for Max and usually go with Blender. On the other side, Max is more industry standard and some like to know that they use what the Pros use.